# Entity Framework multiple relationships between tables

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've have two tables in my project which are User and InvoiceLine.

It has been specified that an `InvoiceLine` can have a `User` known as a Checker.

My models are:

```
public class InvoiceLine : IEntity
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual int? CheckerId { get; set; }
        public virtual string CreatedByUserName { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
        public virtual string LastModifiedByUserName { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }

        // Navigation properties
        public virtual User Checker{ get; set; }
}



public class User : IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CreatedByUserName { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
        public string LastModifiedByUserName { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }

        //Navigation properties
        public virtual ICollection<InvoiceLine> InvoiceLines { get; set; }
    }
```

So this was fine I have a 0..1 to many relationship from `User` to `InvoiceLine`.

This meant with Linq I could get the InvoiceLines the User needs to check via:

```
user.InvoiceLines
```

However there is another requirement that an `InvoiceLine` also has an `Auditor` so I modified the `InvoiceLine` to:

```
public class InvoiceLine : IEntity
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual int? CheckerId { get; set; }
        public virtual int? AuditorId { get; set; }
        public virtual string CreatedByUserName { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
        public virtual string LastModifiedByUserName { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }

        // Navigation properties}
        public virtual User Checker { get; set; }
        public virtual User Auditor { get; set; }
}
```

So what I was really wanting was to go:

```
user.InvoiceLines
```

and get the `Checkers` and `Auditors` or alternatively get them seperately via:

```
user.CheckerInvoiceLines
user.AuditorInvoiceLines
```

I'm getting null back from `user.InvoiceLines` though which is understandable.

Could someone please point me in the right direction on how to use Linq to get the `InvoiceLines` from the `User`?

**Edit Update:**

My model configuration code is like:

```
public class VectorCheckContext : DbContext
    {
        ...

        public DbSet<InvoiceLine> InvoiceLines { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        ...

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post your model configuration code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use fluent mappings to configure the relationships when EF can not resolve them by conventions.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        //other mappings

        modelBuilder.Entity<InvoiceLine>()
           .HasOptional(i => i.Checker)
           .WithMany(u => u.CheckerInvoiceLines)
           .HasForeignKey(i => i.CheckerId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<InvoiceLine>()
           .HasOptional(i => i.Auditor)
           .WithMany(u => u.AuditorInvoiceLines)
           .HasForeignKey(i => i.AuditorId);
    }
```

Comment: Great, that's what I was after. Thanks!